# My first count gets updated by my second count?

Tags: sql

The database we use is structured in a way that we have a table for Training Programs, one for Training Events linked to the Training Program one, then another one for Training Event Activities that are linked to the Training Event. There's a lot more but that's the basics.

I joined the training event and activity tables together, then the training program to the training event tables.

In my select statement I did two counts, one of TrainingEvent.guTrainingProgramId (linked column that relates to TrainingProgram.rowguid). If I remove all instances of Training Event Activity I get what seems to be an accurate represenation of a count of the number of events for each entry in the Training Program table. However once I add in the count of TrainingEventActivity.guTrainingEventId (link to Training Event table) I get an accurate count of the total number of activities, however the coun in the TrainingEvent count changes to reflect the count of activities.

I essentially want to know a count of the number of times that TrainingEvent.guTrainingProgramId = TrainingProgram.rowguid, and a second count where TrainingEventActivity.guTrainingEventId = TrainingEvent.rowguid.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your SQL, your basic table schema, and your desired output.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your sql, it's hard to tell.  But my initial thought would be you'll need to do a count distinct instead of count on the id.   Oh well.   Let's see the SQL.